# Javascript: define, select, and print context of any clicked node from an html document?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

My html document is a digital edition of a text. Each word is contained by an `<a>` element (i.e. it's hyperlinked) and lines are broken with `<br/>`. There are also occasionally block quotations marked off with `<p>`. It thus looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div>Digital Edition Part 1</div>
        <p>
            <a id="[uid]">Words</a> <a id="[uid]">in</a> <a id="[uid]">my</a><br />
            <a id="[uid]">digital</a> <a id="[uid]">edition</a>
<div>
        <p style="margin-left: 30px">
            <a id="[uid]">Block</a> <a>quotation</a><br />
            <a id="[uid]">here</a>
        </p>
</div>
        <a id="[uid]">More</a> <a id="[uid]">Words</a> <a id="[uid]">in</a> <a id="[uid]">the</a><br/>
        <a id="[uid]">digital</a> <a id="[uid]">edition</a>
            </p>
    </div>
</body>
<backmatter>Some endnotes</backmatter>
```

I am working on a javascript application that will print a short "factfile" on each word in the digital edition when a user clicks on it. I want this to include the word's immediate context, say, 2 words/nodes in each direction from the clicked word. Thus, a click on "my" in line 4 of the above code would print the context:

> Words in **my**
>
> digital

That the `<br/>` element is included at the expense of a word **isn't** a high priority problem for me.

This is my current javascript function:

```
function getContext() {
    var el = document.getElementById(id); // this gets the clicked <a> element
    var form = el.outerHTML;
    var el_plus_1 = el.nextElementSibling.outerHTML;
    var el_minus_1 = el.previousElementSibling.outerHTML;
    var el_plus_2 = el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.outerHTML;
    var el_minus_2 = el.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.outerHTML;
    var context = el_minus_2.concat(' ', el_minus_1, ' ', '<b>' + form + '</b>', ' ', el_plus_1, ' ', el_plus_2);
} // context is ready to use as a variable in the function that produces the factfile
```

This works fine if a word in the middle of a block of text is clicked (e.g. "my"), as the context will only catch `<a>` or `<br/>` elements, which are both legitimate elements in the context. However, if user clicks the last word in a`<div/>` or the last word before a `<div>` subdivision, then the function either finds a sibling node that isn't an `<a>` or a `<br/>` or fails to find a sibling node altogether. It then either includes unwanted material (e.g. the entire `<div>` subdivision) in the `context` variable or fails altogether.

How do I specify in the function that:

1. Only `<a>` and `<br/>` elements are to be included in `context`?
2. If the `nextElementSibling` is not `<a>` or `<br/>`, the function should not fail but simply return whatever `<a>` or `<br/>` elements it could get?

In terms of 1., some possibilities have occurred to me but I can't work out how to implement them:

- `filter()`, so that elements other than `<a>` and `<br/>` are ignored. However, having looked at lots of examples of `filter()` in use, I can't work out how to apply it here.
- `getElementsByTagName("a")`, then select exactly which `<a>` using the elements position relative to the clicked `<a>` (I am willing to sacrifice getting the `<br>` elements for a stable function). However, again, I can't work out how to specify position relative to a node. I tried `getElementsByTagName("a")[el+1]` and this selected a very far flung `<a>` node elsewhere in the document. So the principal seems promising but I don't understand how to make it work.

In terms of 2., I am aware of if...else statements but how do I specify that the function should end and return early?

Thank you, if only for reading this far ;-)

Comment: You should **not nest** `<p>` elements. It's silly and AFAIK illegal. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: What is `id` in `var el = document.getElementById(id);` ? Your HTML sample provides no ID elements yet there it shines in your JS

Comment: `value` is not a valid `<div>` attribute. What is `<backmatter>`? OxygenXML?

Comment: Thanks. This is not my actual code but a quick mock-up for discussion purposes (evidently too quick). So problems here are not necessarily relevant to the issue. However, I have updated my question in line with your suggestions.

Comment: You might want to try a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) with a custom [node filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, eventually, I worked out a solution. It isn't pretty and I am sure there are more elegant/efficient ways of achieving the same results. But this got me what I needed (for now...).

Essentially, I needed to break the process down into steps and add if/else if/else statements to catch possible exceptions at each stage while defining which elements I wanted and which ones I didn't want. This solution relies on only elements that are to be included in the context having the `@id` attribute.

```
function getContext() {
var el = document.getElementById(id); // THIS GETS THE CLICKED <a> ELEMENT
var form = el.outerHTML;
var el_plus_1; // THIS CHECKS IF THERE IS A NEXT SIBLING ELEMENT AND SELECTS IT IF SO 
if (el == el.parentNode.lastElementChild) {
    el_plus_1 = "";
    }
    else if (el.nextElementSibling == null) {
    el_plus_1 = "";
    }
    else {el_plus_1 = el.nextElementSibling}
var el_minus_1; // THIS CHECKS IF THERE IS A PREV SIBLING ELEMENT AND SELECTS IT IF SO 
if (el == el.parentNode.firstElementChild) {
    el_minus_1 = "";    
    }
    if (el.previousElementSibling == null) {
    el_minus_1 = "";
    }
    else {el_minus_1 = el.previousElementSibling}
var el_plus_2; // THIS CHECKS IF THERE IS A NEXT+1 SIBLING ELEMENT AND SELECTS IT IF SO 
if (el == el.parentNode.lastElementChild) {
    el_plus_2 = "";
    }
    else if (el.nextElementSibling == el.parentNode.lastElementChild) {
    el_plus_2 = ""; 
    }
    else if (el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling == null) {
    el_plus_2 = "";
    }
    else {el_plus_2 = el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling}
var el_minus_2; // THIS CHECKS IF THERE IS A PREV-1 SIBLING ELEMENT AND SELECTS IT IF SO 
if (el == el.parentNode.firstElementChild) {
    el_minus_2 = "";    
    }
    else if (el.previousElementSibling == el.parentNode.firstElementChild) {
    el_minus_2 = "";    
    }
    else if (el.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling == null) {
    el_minus_2 = "";
    }
    else {el_minus_2 = el.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling}
var el_plus_1Id; // THIS GETS THE ID FOR NEXT, IF IT HAS AN ID
    if (el_plus_1.id == null) {
    el_plus_1Id = "";   
    }
    else {el_plus_1Id = el_plus_1.id}
var el_minus_1Id; // THIS GETS THE ID FOR PREV, IF IT HAS AN ID
    if (el_minus_1.id == null) {
    el_minus_1Id = "";  
    }
    else {el_minus_1Id = el_minus_1.id}
var el_plus_2Id; // THIS GETS THE ID FOR NEXT+1, IF IT HAS AN ID
    if (el_plus_2.id == null) {
    el_plus_2Id = "";   
    }
    else {el_plus_2Id = el_plus_2.id}
var el_minus_2Id; // THIS GETS THE ID FOR PREV-1, IF IT HAS AN ID
    if (el_minus_2.id == null) {
    el_minus_2Id = "";  
    }
    else {el_minus_2Id = el_minus_2.id}
var el_plus_1node; // THIS SELECTS THE NEXT DESIRED ELEMENT AND ALL CHILDREN, IF IT HAS AN ID. IF NOT, AN EMPTY STRING IS RETURNED INSTEAD.
    if (el_plus_1Id === "") {
    el_plus_1node = "";
    }
    else {el_plus_1node = document.getElementById(el_plus_1Id).outerHTML}
var el_minus_1node; // THIS SELECTS THE PREV DESIRED ELEMENT AND ALL CHILDREN, IF IT HAS AN ID. IF NOT, AN EMPTY STRING IS RETURNED INSTEAD.
    if (el_minus_1Id === "") {
    el_minus_1node = "";
    }
    else {el_minus_1node = document.getElementById(el_minus_1Id).outerHTML}
var el_plus_2node; // THIS SELECTS THE NEXT+1 DESIRED ELEMENT AND ALL CHILDREN, IF IT HAS AN ID. IF NOT, AN EMPTY STRING IS RETURNED INSTEAD.
    if (el_plus_2Id === "") {
    el_plus_2node = "";
    }
    else {el_plus_2node = document.getElementById(el_plus_2Id).outerHTML}
var el_minus_2node; // THIS SELECTS THE PREV-1 DESIRED ELEMENT AND ALL CHILDREN, IF IT HAS AN ID. IF NOT, AN EMPTY STRING IS RETURNED INSTEAD.
    if (el_minus_2Id === "") {
    el_minus_2node = "";
    }
    else {el_minus_2node = document.getElementById(el_minus_2Id).outerHTML}
var context = el_minus_2.concat(' ', el_minus_1, ' ', '<b>' + form + '</b>', ' ', el_plus_1, ' ', el_plus_2); 
// THIS SLOTS ALL THE SELECTED CONTEXT NODES TOGETHER, RETURNING EITHER THE NODES AND CHILD ELEMENTS OR EMPTY/INVISIBLE STRINGS.
```

Answer (score -1):

You were really close with the getElementsByTagName ideas. As it sounds like you want to go through all a tags you can query for all of them and then just go in the direction once you've found the one that isn't the clicked on:

```
function getContext() {
    var el = document.getElementById(id)
    var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    for(var x = 0; x < aTags.length; x++){
        if(aTags[x] === el){
            aTags[x - 1];//1 before
            aTags[x - 2];//2 before
            aTags[x + 1];//1 after
            aTags[x + 2];//2 after
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I have noticed some extra complexity in my code that makes this solution temporarily unviable (some `<a>` elements are nested in other `<a>` elements - this means that aTags.length can't be calculated, as the `<a>` elements aren't in a continuous sequence...). So I am going to find a way of fixing that (a product of the XSLT transformation) and will then give your solution a fair try!

Comment: Hi Matthew! Unfortunately, I couldn't get this working, even after tidying up my HTML. In itself, your solution seems perfectly logical and I am sorry that I don't have the knowledge to give you better feedback on why it didn't work.